# Paypal merchant acceept or deny each transcation

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm developing website for online shopping in which i have integrate paypal as payment method.

but, i want each transaction must be confirmed by merchant so that merchant can accept or reject(decline-deny) each transaction.

payments for the rejected transaction will be refunded to payer. and accepted transaction will we processed as confirmed order.

is their any way to do this ?

### please help me on this. thanks in advance

I found my answer.

now i will go with "paypal authorization capture api"
for this i need to use paymentaction="authorization" in my paypal  standard payment form that make the transaction on hold.

and at admin side i need to make that onhold transaction make capture to proceed order or  void orders to cancel i just need transaction id their.

i will use "paypal authorize and capture api" for that...

Answer (score 0):

you should manually lo-gin into you merchant account to reject(decline-deny) each transaction.